# Timed motor switch

Tags: motor, switches, dc

I'm very new with electronics and I'm working on a project, I need to make a motor go forward then after a few seconds reverse, then forward then reverse and so on. I found this tutorial ([How to control a DC motor to run in both directions](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-control-a-DC-motor-to-run-in-both-direction/)) which is great but it uses a manual switch. Does anyone know how I could make this so its timed to switch?

Comment: Two relays and timing device, this can be MCU, NE555, whatever you have intended. You coud use also a H-brdge instead of relays.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an IC 555 timer to control motor as H-bridge, please see [here](http://www.science20.com/square_root_of_not/robotics_555_timer_hbridge-145691). Be careful about current required by your motor because the circuit does not use any transistor as drivers. An IC 555 output can source or sink 200 mA.

The better solution is connecting [DC-motor H-bridge circuit](http://www.talkingelectronics.com/projects/H-Bridge/H-Bridge-1.html) to the output of 555 or microcontroller for a more flexible solution.